# Is there a way to make Google Earth only display the outline of continents?

Tags: visualisation, google-earth

I want to do a visualization in Google Earth and I don't want to see all the different colours of the satellite images. Instead I'd like just the outline of the continents/coastlines, maybe a colour distinction between land and water, but that's it. Is there a way to set Google Earth so it doe this?

I don't want any textures, just solid colour preferably. Like the ocean floor, I'd like to not see that. Same with land, just one colour would be preferable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need a KML file of the world borders as polygons. A quick Google turned up [this](http://www.gelib.com/world-borders.htm) Which seems to be pretty much what you want.

I'm not sure if there is a water polygon in that dataset, so you may still have the sea floor. If that's the case, you'll need to import the KML file into something like [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org), create a rectangular polygon covering the whole world, and subtract the country polygons from it. Then export it back as KML and load it into GE.

Comment: After dling QGIS and playing with it a bit, I decided that I'd actually rather do my visualization in it! Thanks for the help. Anyone looking at this answer and still wants to use Google Earth should check out the other answer as I added comments on how to block out land/seafloor in Google Earth

Answer (score 2):

A global image overlay file is one method. I have no experience of [**this company**](http://kmzmaps.com/), but their product seems to be what you need and they have different styles from around $5

Comment: This site looks promising

Comment: Also this [site](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) has some land and ocean overlays that I was able to import into Quantum GIS and then export as KML (specifically under [here](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/))